# How to find the xpath of the scroll bar/button?

Tags: javascript, html, selenium-webdriver, xpath, selenium-chromedriver

I'm using selenium to open up an instagram page and scrolling through a list of followers. However, I'm having issues with this line of code here:
`self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[1]/section/nav/div[2]/div/div/div[3]/div/div[5]/span").click()`

The scroll bar/button element's xpath isn't correct, and I don't know how to find the correct xpath.

[Here's](https://github.com/omarbabu/instabot/blob/master/GramBot.py) the source code (original repo + specific file) I pulled from and started editing from there.

Comment: could you provide the full script you are using? the problem is that you are not able to scroll down?

Comment: Yup basically. The xpath element is just not correct (I assume the xpath is deprecated b/c the original programmer hasn't modified the code in a while).

Comment: using the `find_elements` method are you able to get the list of followers? if you are able to do so, then i can tell you how to scroll into each item of the list. if you want you can give me the url to the page where the list of followers is, so i can get it by myself

Answer (score 0):

### Selenium Scrolling

There are **multiple ways to scroll** down a webpage in Selenium in order to load new information. The **simplest and most effective** way I have found was using the Selenium.Keys method:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

body = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('body')
body.click()
body.send_keys(Keys.PAGE_DOWN)
```

### More Information

I *highly recommend* you go through this guide if you have not already:

https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/getting-started.html

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest 3 options here (examples are in Java):

1. If you know exactly element what needs to become in viewport you can use following

   WebElement el = driver.findElement(By.xpath("xpath"));

   JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
   js.executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView()",el);
2. Use sendKeys method mentioned here already
   WebElement el = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//body"));
   el.sendKeys(Keys.PAGE_DOWN)
3. The most tricky option, find element which has css property 'overflow' with value that makes scroll bar to appear e.g. overflow: 'auto' and using JavaScript you will be able to know exactly scrolling point and scroll in any direction as you like

   WebElement el = driver.findElement(By.xpath("xpath")); 
   JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver; 
   int scrollAmountInPx = 10;
   js.executeScript("arguments[0].scrollTo(0, arguments[0].scrollTop + " + scrollAmountInPx+ ")",el);

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```py
element=self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[1]/section/nav/div[2]/div/div/div[3]/div/div[5]/span")

self.driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", element)

element.click()
```

Comment: Late response, but this didn't work :(. It's still giving me the same error.